# jQuery Cycle creating too many pager links

Tags: jquery, expressionengine, jquery-cycle

I've searched and search but can't seem to find any decent results for this query.

Basically I have pages being pulled in via ajax - including images - but jquery cycle is creating a ton of entries for the pager, and only some of the links work. However, if I target the images more specifically (just targeting #images instead of #img-container #images), the pager counts correctly, but then the pager links don't work. It's driving me nuts!

The HTML output from expressionengine is sound, it's just placing all the img tags from the query inside the #images div with no problems. All very clean.

Here's the jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "url_is_here",
 data: {'entryId':entryId},
 success: function(data){
      $("#work .entry").html(data);
      $('#img-container #images').cycle({
            fx:     'fade',
            speed:  'slow',
            timeout: 5000,
            pause:  1,
            pager:  '.img-nav',
      });
}
```

And the HTML (minus the other expressionengine stuff):

```
<div id="img-container">
<div id="images">
    {work-images}{exp:imgsizer:size image="{image}" width="600" alt="{caption}"}{/work-images}  </div>
<div class="img-nav">
</div>
```

Here's the result of an instance with 9 images:
http://cl.ly/2Q25292L1u222a333y2Q

And how it looks in firebug (fine as far as I can tell, minus the img-nav being flooded with 'a' tags, hence why it's closed):
http://cl.ly/3a402X3q1Q2r0q0i2m1u

Any help would be immensely appreciated. I apologise in advance if there's anything amiss with my post, I'm a first-timer here :)

Many thanks,
Marcel

Comment: Is your pager navigation being built by ExpressionEngine or by jQuery Cycle? You may just need to write a [pagerAnchorBuilder](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html) function for your custom pager links. It would be helpful to see a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the output your HTML/CSS and JavaScript, so we could better understand your markup.

Answer (score 1):

rjb is right, the PageAnchorBuilder function controls the pager and it depends on how you're generating the markup.

One way to do this is with Matrix, and call the Channel Field loop twice: once for the images, once for the pager.

```
    {!-- SLIDE IMAGES --}
    <div id="cycle">
        {cf_slide_tag_pair}
            <a href="{slide_link}"><img src="{slide_image}" /></a>
        {/cf_slide_tag_pair}
    </div>

    {!-- PAGER --}
    <ul id="pager">
        {cf_slide_tag_pair}
          <li><a href="#">{slide_title}</a></li>
        {/cf_slide_tag_pair}
    </ul>

    {!-- CYCLE CALL --}
    $('#cycle').cycle({
       activePagerClass: 'active',
       pager: '#pager',
       pause: 1,
       speed: 'fast',
       timeout: 22000,
       pagerAnchorBuilder: function(index, slide) {
         return '#pager li:eq('+(idx)+') a';
       }
    });
```